# How to do a calendar with jQuery (slide days as carousel)? No grid days. Only carousel days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js, bxslider

I'm developing a calendar, which the days are shown with BX Slider.
Seven days are shown at time.
After click left arrow, previous 7 days are shown. Click right arrow, nexts 7 days are shown.

Reference: https://www.munchkinfun.com/miami/cal

Quite simple, but...

I tried [Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/), FlexSlider and [BX Slider](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4). Slick and BX Slider came closer to the expected result. But both have some bugs. I posted the issues in both GitHubs, but I don't know if is possible to do what I want with other settings or other plugins.

### Slick Slider

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3x0cznq/1/

`$(".slider").slick({
    infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 7,
      slidesToScroll: 5,
      dots: false,
      initialSlide: 24,
      edgeFriction: 0,
});`

Bug 1: Click left arrow to the first position and note that left edge is not reached. Left arrow finishes in day 04.

Bug 2: Change the `active` class to day 28 and run fiddle. Click left arrow and note that dots changed, but slick doesn't sliding.

### BX Slider

There a similar bug. if 'moveSlides' == 1 then all works.
if 'moveSlides' > 1, the "dots navigation" doesn't changes, which indicates that some calcs are wrong. In the same fiddle, I have an option `startSlide` which doesn't works too. If uncomment the line and change `moveSlides` to 1, start slide will be DOMINGO 07 out. Note that the last day don't be reached.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w3a97zyh/

What I want to do is quite simple, but I've been trying for a lot of days and I can not to solve.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up the plugins Slick and BX Slider. I tried [jCarousel](https://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) and works fine. It's a little bit more work than others, because has no default CSS, BUT has no bugs (in my use).

Here's the fiddle with the final result: https://jsfiddle.net/m9nurv2f/10/

My default settings (please, see the fiddle):

```
$('.jcarousel')
.on('jcarousel:createend', function() {
    $(this).jcarousel('scroll', $('.jcarousel li:eq('+get_initialSlide($('.jcarousel').find("ul"))+')'), false);
}).jcarousel();

$('.jcarousel-prev').on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
}).on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
    $(this).addClass('inactive');
}).jcarouselControl({
    target: '-=7'
});
```